# What does this notation means $\mathbb{F}_{2^{-}}$?

Tags: spn, diffusion

I have seen various papers to use this notation $\mathbb{F}_{2^{-}}$ to describe the diffusion layer. As for example the permutation in AES (MixColumns).
So, we have a field with order of 2, what does the minus sign means?

I have tried to search for the term in finite fields lectures and papers but none explained what it actually means.

Here are couple of references: (and generally i have seen it used when they discuss about the diffusion layer)

[On sbox affine equivalent page2](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/085.pdf)

[Progress in Cryptology](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4rK5BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA254&lpg=PA254&dq=F2-%20sbox&source=bl&ots=6XbYVQExC1&sig=vYkNeJzDA6p8jzNMpXj2jC-aYTg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqv_2th8jSAhXBA8AKHdZcCxgQ6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=F2-%20sbox&f=false)

[The new codebreakers](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NA_NCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=F2-%20sbox&source=bl&ots=fon3jr_g6i&sig=gHqHCsH2TUTbkm-lqtdCZWf83_g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqv_2th8jSAhXBA8AKHdZcCxgQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=F2-%20sbox&f=false)

Comment: Can you please link to a couple of these papers?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it was some common term. I have added some references. I wasn't sure if i should had included it but I have seen it coupled with linear/affine permutation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've been confused by the placement of the "-".

It's not $\mathbb F_{2^-}$ (Latex: `$\mathbb F_{2^-}$`), this does not exist. What was actually meant is $\mathbb F_2$-adjective (Latex: `$\mathbb F_2$-adjective`), where the hyphen binds the field and the adjective (eg "linear" or "affine") to bring more specific meaning to the adjective.

Example:

> [...]with an $\mathbb F_2$-affine permutation[...]

You would have read "with a permutation that is affine in $\mathbb F_{2^-}$" as opposed to the intended meaning of "with a permutation that is affine in $\mathbb F_2$".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I figured that this could be the case, but the references to that was consistently used with -, so i figured that is some kind of notation.